# Calling OnClientClick from Code behind in Asp.net VB

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have code like this :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="HL_KonfirmasiPemesanan" class="button-primary button-shadow" causesvalidation="false" validationgroup="ValidasiData"  OnClientClick="return getConfirmation(this);"  ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Then I want call `OnClientClick="return getConfirmation(this);"` in code behind, I tried:

```
HL_KonfirmasiPemesanan.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return getConfirmation(this);")
```

but it doesn't work, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
dim script as String = "<script>var btn = document.querySelector('.button-primary'); getConfirmation(btn);</script>"
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "click_Btn", script)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great answer!

Comment: You welcome my friend... Please remember that it is better to select your button by it's id, `var btn = document.querySelector('#HL_KonfirmasiPemesanan')` . But I don't know if you are using a `MasterPage` or not. If yes the id will be some thing like this: `contentPlaceHolder1_HL_KonfirmasiPemesanan` related to your `contentPlaceHolder` name.